# How to download an attachment from couchdb using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb

I have a document like below in the couchdb

```
{
  "_id":"test",
  "_rev":"2-test",
  "data":"some additional fields with info about the image",
  "_attachments":
  {
    "foo.jpg":
    {
      "stub":true,
      "content_type":"image/jpeg",
      "length":23721
    }
  }
}
```

Am trying to fetch the attachments by looping and object.attachment_url(filename). But it is failed to download

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it requires a File object, you just need to make one that pretends it's one... try creating a class that subclasses StringIO. Construct it to the binary data of the image URL, and just add a path? method that returns something that will (hopefully) satisfy CouchRest.

Comment: Can you please exlpain with some example?